# Update Statement on one table takes locks on other tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, locking, concurrency

Given the following statement on the AdventureWorks database:

`UPDATE Sales.SalesOrderDetail SET OrderQty = 100 WHERE ModifiedDate >= '2014-01-01'`

If I open another query window and look at the locks the query is using by running

`sp_WhoIsActive @get_locks =1`

i can see locks as follows:

```
   <Object name="Person" schema_name="Person">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="X" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
    <Object name="SalesOrderDetail" schema_name="Sales">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="X" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
    <Object name="SalesOrderHeader" schema_name="Sales">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="X" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
```

I was expecting the table lock on SalesOrderDetail however, I don't understand why the table lock has been taken on the Person Table and the SalesOrderHeader table

I can confirm the locks are present by trying to `SELECT *` from one of the tables which is then blocked.

Why are tables that are not being updated locked by the update statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The tables are being locked due to the trigger: `[iduSalesOrderDetail]` on `[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]`**

[image]

The trigger launches if any of these actions occur:

```
IF UPDATE([ProductID]) OR UPDATE([OrderQty]) OR UPDATE([UnitPrice]) OR UPDATE([UnitPriceDiscount])
```

And `UPDATE([OrderQty])` is one of these actions.

**This trigger will then update `Person.Person` two times.**

One of these `Update` statements:

```
  UPDATE [Person].[Person] 
            SET [Demographics].modify('declare default element namespace 
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/IndividualSurvey"; 
                replace value of (/IndividualSurvey/TotalPurchaseYTD)[1] 
                with data(/IndividualSurvey/TotalPurchaseYTD)[1] + sql:column ("inserted.LineTotal")') 
            FROM inserted 
                INNER JOIN [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] AS SOH
                ON inserted.[SalesOrderID] = SOH.[SalesOrderID] 
                INNER JOIN [Sales].[Customer] AS C
                ON SOH.[CustomerID] = C.[CustomerID]
            WHERE C.[PersonID] = [Person].[Person].[BusinessEntityID];
```

**And also `Sales.SalesOrderHeader`**

```
 UPDATE [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]
        SET [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader].[SubTotal] = 
            (SELECT SUM([Sales].[SalesOrderDetail].[LineTotal])
                FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]
                WHERE [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader].[SalesOrderID] = [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail].[SalesOrderID])
        WHERE [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader].[SalesOrderID] IN (SELECT inserted.[SalesOrderID] FROM inserted);
```

Explaining the Exclusive locks on these objects.

Comment: I looked in keys and constraints to try to find refererences to the other tables and couldn't find any.....I should have kept looking a bit further down the object explorer :) Thanks - makes perfect sense

Comment: @SEarle1986 That would have also been a possibility! What helped me was remembering that AdventureWorks has some crazy triggers :).

Comment: Another good way to track these down is to turn on actual execution plan for the query.  That innocent looking UPDATE turned out to be 12 different queries!